# Notepad++ Search by Columns

Tags: notepad++

I would like to search a file only on the first column based on a set of IDs from another file. Copy and paste the results to another output file.

For example ,

My first file contains

```
ABHA-PHY49M
ABHA-PHY49N
ABHA-PHY49O
```

My second file contains

```
"ABHA-PHY49M";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHY49N";"Hi,
Some mail contents1
Kind Regards,"

"ABHA-8RXIYY";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHY49N";"Hi,
Some mail contents2
Kind Regards,"

"ABHA-PHY49M";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHYCCC";"Hi,
Some mail contents3
Kind Regards,"

"ABHA-8RXIXX";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHYDDD";"Hi,
Some mail contents4
Kind Regards,"
```

I need to retrieve all lines matching the ids from the first file with the first column value. I cant use excel because there is a field called Verbatim where the contents could be free text and would contain CR+LF etc which destroys the formatting when opening with Excel. 
I would like to know if we can write/record a macro to achieve this. All I can think of is to search the ids(obtained from file1) and search in the first column , extend the selection and copy the data. Not sure if this is possible or how to do it.

In the above example , just two rows will be selected because of the Id **`ABHA-PHY49M`**

```
"ABHA-PHY49M";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHY49N";"Hi,
Some mail contents1
Kind Regards,"

"ABHA-PHY49M";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHYCCC";"Hi,
Some mail contents3
Kind Regards,"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a regular expression search? If it is definitely the first column you're searching in, then this should work:

```
^"ABHA-PHY49M".*$
```

- The first character `^` ensures that it will only search at the beginning of the line.
- The literal characters `"ABHA-PHY49M"` match the string you're looking for.
- The remaining characters `.*$` include the entire rest of the line.

The search results I get, from your sample data, look right:

```
Search "^"ABHA-PHY49M".*$" (2 hits in 1 file)
  new  5 (2 hits)
    Line 1: "ABHA-PHY49M";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHY49N";"Hi, Some mail contents1 Kind Regards,"
    Line 5: "ABHA-PHY49M";"Blah blah";"Ashwin";"";"10/14/2 009 10:36:29";"ABHA-PHYCCC";"Hi, Some mail contents3 Kind Regards,"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [SQL Plugin](http://www.scout-soft.com/sql/) allows execute SQL database commands in CSV files. 
In your case query would be:

```
 select * from data where id="abha-phy49m"
```

if first column is called "id" (commands case insensitive). This will retrieve all lines from current file where id is "abha-phy49m"

EDIT: Unfortunately it converts output text to lowercase